# Can I set authorization headers with RequireJS?

Tags: authentication, requirejs

We want to have 2 sets of resources for our AngularJS app (public/private) which uses RequireJS for dependency management. Basically everything on the login page would be public and once logged in, another angularjs app would be loaded (new requirejs config) that would load resources that require authentication to access.

Is there a way to configure requirejs to set an authorization header when loading resources?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "resources" and how your server is configured. But in general - yes, since you are using AngularJS you can use the $httpProvider to inject an interceptor service.

For example, in a service:

```
        var dependencies = ['$rootScope', 'userService'];

        var service = function ($rootScope, userService) {
            return {
                request: function(config) {
                    var currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
                    var access_token = currentUser ? currentUser.access_token : null;

                    if(access_token) {
                        config.headers.authorization = access_token;
                    }
                    return config;
                },
                responseError: function (response) {
                    if(response.status === 401) {
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('unauthorized');
                    }
                    return response;
                }
            };
        };

        module.factory(name, dependencies.concat(service));
```

Then, after you configure your routes, you can use:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push( 'someService');
```

You can find some more information on interceptors here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors

---

**UPDATE**

You might be able to use the text plugin to try and receive it, but I don't see the point in protecting client side code. Plus, if you want to use optimization the resources will just come in one file anyway...

```
 config: {
        text: {
            onXhr: function (xhr, url) {
               xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + token);
            }
        }
    }
```

Refer to: [custom-xhr-hooks](https://github.com/requirejs/text#custom-xhr-hooks)

---

**Another UPDATE**

You could also use urlArgs (mainly used for cache invalidation) without using the text plugin:

```
require.config({
    urlArgs: 'token='+token,
    ...
)}
```

Comment: Heheh I'm already doing that within Angular. What I mean is when requirejs loads a javascript file from the server can I pass authentication headers along with those javascript file requests?

Comment: Thanks @Shapeshifter, securing client-side code may sound a little goofy, but we're just being cautious. No point exposing things to unauthenticated users that don't need to see.

Comment: No Problem, you could also consider using urlArgs, which doesn't touch the header but you'd be able to pass a token or something using that as well. If my answer suits you, please mark it as such! Thanks @SomethingOn