# Load requirejs modules from a secure server with auth token

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs

I am using requirejs with knockout to load some modules from a remote server:

```
ko.components.register("my-component", {
  viewModel: {
    require: 'http://something.com/myModel.js'
  },
  template: {
    require: 'text!http://something.com/myModel.html'
  }
});
```

The problem is, the module I am trying to load, though inside a internal network, is on a secured server, and needs a authentication to access.

Is there any way to add a authentication header to the GET call requirejs/node.js will make for retrieving the component js and html files?

Comment: You might want to see this (if not seen already) - https://www.haykranen.nl/2011/06/21/basic-http-authentication-in-node-js-using-the-request-module/ to see if this solves your purpose...

Comment: Check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656938/can-i-set-authorization-headers-with-requirejs) or you might need to write a plugin, though.